# Converting a long integer into a char/rune

Tags: java, go, casting, char, integer

I am trying to rewrite something I have seen done in Java to Go.

In Java, the example converts the int `1573346` to the char `Ǣ` using the type cast of `(char)1573346;`
After printing the int of the new value I get the decimal ascii of `482;`

```
int num = 1573346;
char ascii = (char)num; // Ǣ
int asciiNum = (int)ascii; // 482
```

I can't find a way to do the same thing in Go.

Comment: Use `rune` instead of `char`

Comment: Is truncating `1573346` to 16bits really what you intend to do here?  The number `1573346` doesn't directly map to a unicode code point, so this result only happens because java internally uses 16bits for the character.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the use-case for this? (It doesn't seem like "real" Java code: it's the sort of code you write to illustrate the quirks of casting, not because you actually want those quirks.)

Comment: The use-case was for xor encryption using a secret key. The code above is just the part that wasn't working when using rune instead of char.

Comment: You do realize that `'Ǣ'` and `482` are the exact same value? Just now it turned out to me that this question was not even asking about 'conversion' of values but trying to ask how to render the same value in different format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `char` type is 2 bytes or 16 bits. When you do `(char)num` in Java, that will "trim" `num` to 16 bits, keeping the lowest 16 bits.

To do the same in Go, first convert the number to `uint16` for example, and then to `rune` (and optionally to `string` for printing).

Note that in Go you can't convert the constant value `1573346` to `uint16` because the number is not representable by a value of type `uint16`. So you first have to assign it to a variable and convert the value of the variable (which is allowed):

```
x := 1573346
fmt.Println(string(rune(uint16(x))))
```

Which outputs:

```
Ǣ
```

The same as:

```
fmt.Println(string(rune(482)))
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dJrPFiI2nN4).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked great. I just used string(rune(uint16(x))) and it worked. I was sure that it was to do with the int type but couldn't find anything in the java docs.

Answer (score -1):

https://play.golang.org/p/1eVgDANNTUT

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num = int(1573346)
    var ascii = uint16(num)
    var asciiNum = int(ascii)

    fmt.Printf("%d %c %d", num, ascii, asciiNum)
}
```

```
1573346 Ǣ 482
Program exited.
```